# Create a pop up window after signing up for the first time in moodle

Tags: php, plugins, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

I am new to Moodle and I am trying to have a pop up window when an user logged in for the first time. I have created a custom plugin, in there I have made a custom page consist of a form. Is there any way that I can make that form page appear as a pop up after an user logged in for the first time?
I am using Moodle version 3.11.7 and PHP 7.4.29.
Any help with the Moodle development would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle 3+ has "User Tours" which will probably do what you need

You can display a pop up after a user has logged in for the first time

Go to Site Admin > Appearance > User Tours

Create a new tour, for the URL to match use "FRONTPAGE" which will be the home page

Save and then click on the name of the tour you just created

On the next page, click "Next step"

For "Target type" select "Middle of page"

Then enter the title and content and save

Then login as a different user and click on the home page to display the popup

Detailed instructions are here : https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/User_tours

There is also a Moodle video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhLVvyP3DU0

Comment: I have one more question - can I add the tour to my custom page that I made in custom plugin? and does Moodle allow me to add a form into that pop up page?
Thanks for your time and help. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Shihab - yeah you can use user tours on any url - click on the help (?) icon when creating the tour. I don't know about forms though, you'll need to look through the documentation